# How do I get an array of unique values in my controller that is NOT connected to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table named Donations which has a column named season.  Season contains the actual season the donation was made in... like 2011 or 2010, etc.

I also have a controller named ReportController that would like to pass a unique list of seasons from the Donations table.

In the ReportController, how do I get an array of those unique values?  Is there something like `@valid_seasons = Donations.find(:all).unique{|x| x.season}` that I use in my reportcontroller?  Will I then be able to pass @valid_seasons as an option for  select statement in the views/report/foo.html.erb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [uniq_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by)

```
Donations.all.uniq_by{|x| x.season}
```

However this still executes a `select *` on your table.

You might be better off with using [raw sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql).  Something like:

```
 Donations.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM donations GROUP BY season")
```

The first example will retrieve all the records and then filter.  The second will only fetch the first row for each unique season.

Comment: Hmmm... so it since there really will only be a few seasons, it might be best to create a separate table with the seasons in them and just look through that table to get what seasons are possible?  Then put a season_id in the donations table and have new records be added automatically to the seasons table when a donation is created for a new season.  Does that sound about the best to way to do it and keep from having to do a complete table scan?

Comment: Oh... I can do that?  Cool.. so I might actually want to do something like this: `@valid_seasons = Donations.find_by_sql("SELECT season from donations group by season")` to get only the seasons that are possible which I can use in the select box to allow the user to select which seasons they want.  Then I can use Donation.season_scope(:params[:season]) or something to only get the rows associated with the season they select.  excellent, thanks!

Comment: @AaronThomas Yeah, you can do this.  Just be careful about doing so, you need to do your own escaping (don't just interpolate the string) and try and stick to SQL standards to make things easier if you ever change your database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if this is rails 3 but, if so, this should do the trick:

```
Donations.select(:season).group(:season)
```

This will execute a proper group by:

```
SELECT season FROM "donations" GROUP BY season
```

Comment: Ooh.  Yes, this is rails 3.  I will give that a shot... as well, thank you!

Comment: Ah yes... just tried this and it is quite fast.  Before I got this answer, I did go through the extra to create a separate table/model for season and just pull that info in which was very fast... but it requires me to add an extra step of adding to that table if someone creates a donation for a new season (which I prefer to avoid if I can).  Fortunately this Donations.select(:season).group(:season) seems to run fast enough to be quite acceptable to use.  So now I will drop that seasons table and the season_id column.  Thank you!

Comment: If these are text/varchar columns, then an index should also speed this up.

Comment: Yup, I had an index on there,but it still ran slow until this: Donations.select(:season).group(:season)   Now it runs like a charm. thanks!